# Is it possible to have multiple Azure sites point to the same project?

Tags: azure

I have a site hosted in Azure with a url of xxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net that points to an MVC project. Is it possible to create another url yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.azurewebsites.net and have it also point to the same MVC project that xxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net points to?

I tried doing this with the "Add hostname" feature, but ended up with the following error:

> Failed to add hostname yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.azurewebsites.net Too many (2) hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since that hostname is essentially `appname.azurewebsites.net`, no.

What you could do to achieve the same effect would be to create two apps with those names, and make them pull the app from the same source control system/push to both from a Continuous Delivery pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but in a roundabout way.

You can host your main site on a Web App at xxx.azurewebsites.net. You can then create a second Web App at yyy.azurewebsites.net. Set up yyy.azurewebsites.net as a reverse proxy to forward all requests to xxx.azurewebsites.net. Since your reverse proxy is just forwarding traffic, you can get by with a really small instance.

Comment: I like this idea but it would be nice to know how exactly to configure it this way.   By reading it and looking at the config settings I really have no clue how to do what you're saying.

Comment: @Mike I am sorry for the delayed response. Here is the article that I used to configure a reverse proxy with an Azure Web App: https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/. If you get stuck or have questions, let me know and I'll see if I can answer them based on my implementation.